# how to add a new item inside an object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**react**
I have that problem. I cant add a new item inside an object

```js
const person = {
    name:"farhan",
    age:"25",
    address:"daka"
};

person.push({profession:"job holder"})
```

Comment: `person['profession']='job holder'`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Pls read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Pls specify exactly what problem you are facing in adding a new item inside an object.

Answer (score 4):

[`.push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) is for arrays. You want to assing value to object like:

```js
person.profession = "job holder"
```